# Making the selection transparent in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, select

Despite setting the layer or the symbology of the features to semi-transparent, when performing a selection, the features become solid. I want to edit those features based on properties of the features/background image below them.

How can I set a transparency when features are selected?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Make selection color transparent by reducing opacity in Set Selection Color window.**

Settings menu > Options > Canvas & Legend > Selection color

[image]

The same setting is available on a project-specific basis in the Project > Properties menu. You may need to restart QGIS to see the changes.

**Here are another few options for making the background visible behind selected features:**

Use an outline symbol type:

[image]

You can pair this with centroid fill:

[image]

Or add multiple, offset outlines for a more filled polygon appearance. The example image below has 6 symbol layers with offsets of 0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6, and 7.5 mm.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant workarounds!  I also managed to get it to be semi-transparent by changing the colour properties themselves under … choose colour... opacity.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think to look for transparency in the color selection window. I'll edit my answer to include that info.

Comment: I have tried this many times, reducing opacity down to c. 5%, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there anything else I need to change? I am currently on 3.6.3 Noosa

Comment: @JimS-W Did you restart QGIS after changing the transparency setting?

Comment: Not immediately, but it has been restarted since, with no obvious result

Comment: I was having the same issue, @JimS-W - got to Project Properties (Ctrl + Shift + P) and then General. You'll see there where you can change the selection color / transparency. I don't know why the above solution didn't work for me, but I had to change it in the project properties instead of Settings.

Comment: Yes, I had to also go into Project Properties, not General QGIS Settings.

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3.10.9, this might not work. Using this path (`Settings > Options > Canvas & Legend > Default Map Appearance`) to change colors/transparency of selected features will be overridden by the project properties. I successfully changed color and transparency of selected features by going to `Project > Properties > General > Selection Color` and making my changes there.